# Win32 API Child window doesn't appear in parent's area

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to write a simple app in Win32 API. The goal is to create a parent window with blue background and a child window (visible as a small red square)  inside it.

I define a parent and child windows:

```
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_GAMEPRACTICE3));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));
    wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_GAMEPRACTICE3);
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
        0,0, 400, 600, HWND_DESKTOP, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Child window

    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpszClassName = childClass;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);


    HWND hwnd_child = CreateWindow(childClass, NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0, 0, 32, 32,
        hWnd, 0, hInst, 0);

    ShowWindow(hwnd_child, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd_child);
```

When I launch the app I get the following output:

[image]

It seems that the child window is not displaying at all.
I tried to search similar problems on the Internet but none of the solutions worked for me so far.

Source code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GamePractice3.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

HINSTANCE hInst;                               
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];              
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];        
WCHAR childClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_GAMEPRACTICE3, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);


    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_GAMEPRACTICE3));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));
    wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_GAMEPRACTICE3);
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_GAMEPRACTICE3));

    MSG msg;

    hInst = hInstance; 

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
        0,0, 400, 600, HWND_DESKTOP, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);


    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpszClassName = childClass;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    HWND hwnd_child = CreateWindow(childClass, NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0, 0, 32, 32,
        hWnd, 0, hInst, 0);


    ShowWindow(hwnd_child, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd_child);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: The child window shouldn't have WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW unless you want it to have a title bar, close button, and borders. Also have you tried different coordinates, maybe 50,50,100,100?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW was for sure part of problem. Changing coordinates didn't help. I actually resolved the issue, I will post the answer so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Child window doesn't appear in parent's area** issue, in addition to @daniel_p's answer:

1. [`WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-windows) style is not relevant here. This style gives the window a title bar, a window menu, a sizing border, and minimize and maximize buttons.
2. [**Error checking**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexa#return-value) is necessary. You will find that register child window class failed and return `0`.
3. Specify a valid null-terminated string for class name. **Class name is `NULL` is one of factors cause `RegisterClassEx` fail.**
4. **Initialize `WNDCLASSEX` struct like: `WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};`** Without initialization, some value which you don't set explicitly later will be garbage value. This is another factor cause `RegisterClassEx` fail. **Or you can set every value explicitly.**

With the following editions your code will work:

```
    WCHAR childClass[MAX_LOADSTRING] = L"Child Window";
// ...
            WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
```

Example for error checking of `RegisterClassEx` function:

```
DWORD errCode = 0;

ATOM childClassId = RegisterClassEx(&wc);
if (!childClassId)
{
    errCode = GetLastError();
    MessageBox(NULL, L"RegisterClassEx failed!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OKCANCEL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue.

- I removed WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW from the creation of the child window
- I added seperate Window Procedure for the child window with
  DefWindowProc
- I created a string for childClass and loaded it (LoadStringW)
- I initialized all 11 fields of WNDCLASSEXW structure (not sure if it's necessary)

Hope it helps.